# Insert & Update entity using Spring MVC, JPA Hibernate, @OneToOne foreign key

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, db2, entity

I am using JPA Hibernate and `@OneToOne` using foreign key approach. I got problem when add & update my data.

My questions are:
1) I just want to insert data into **Customer** table but it insert null value to **CustomerInfo** table as well.
2) I just want to update **Customer** table. But it insert null value to **CustomerInfo** also and update back the `PK` to **Customer**'s `FK`.

> ## Table design
>
> Class: Customer

```
 Customer{
        customerId(PK),
        name,
        customerInfoId(FK)
        }
        CustomerInfo{
        customerInfoId(PK),
        address1,
        address2,
        address3} 



@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "customerInfoId", nullable = true, updatable = true,     insertable = true)
private CustomerInfo customerInfo;
```

## Add NEW CUSTOMER

Input data:

Customer(name="GARY"),
CustomerInfo-No Input(Empty String)<--Spring MVC set it default to empty string.

***Result from DB***:

```
Customer:
customerId("1"),
name("GARY"),
customerInfoId("1")<--this should be null
CustomerInfo:
customerInfoId("1")<--don't know why JPA hibernate insert into this table as there is no data input
```

## UPDATE CUSTOMER

Customer(name='GARY123'),
CustomerInfo-No Input(Empty String)<--Spring mvc by default will set to empty string.

## Result from DB

```
Customer:
customerId("1")
name("GARY123")
customerInfoId("2") - this should be null
CustomerInfo:
customerInfoId("2) - don't know why JPA Hibernate insert into this table as there is no input data
```

*Hibernate SQL for update Customer:*

```
insert into CUSTOMERINFO(CUSTOMERINFOID, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3) values (default, ?, ?, ?);

update CUSTOMER set name =?, customerInfoId = ?  where CUSTOMERID = ?
```

Here is how I call to create & update Customer:

```
 @Override
public void create(CustomerObj obj) {
    Customer entity = new Customer();
    entity.setName(obj.getName());

    CustomerInfo customerInfo = new CustomerInfo();
        customerInfo.setAddress1(obj.getCustomerInfo().getAddress1());
        customerInfo.setAddress2(obj.getCustomerInfo().getAddress2());
        customerInfo.setAddress3(obj.getCustomerInfo().getAddress3());

        entity.setCustomerInfo(customerInfo);

        persistAndFlush(entity);

    }

@Override
    public void update(CustomerObj obj) {
        Customer entity = findById(obj.getCustomerId)
        entity.setName(obj.getName());

        CustomerInfo customerInfo = new CustomerInfo();
            customerInfo.setAddress1(obj.getCustomerInfo().getAddress1());
            customerInfo.setAddress2(obj.getCustomerInfo().getAddress2());
            customerInfo.setAddress3(obj.getCustomerInfo().getAddress3());

            entity.setCustomerInfo(customerInfo);


        }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi @data_henrik , 
My questions are:      
1) I just want to insert data into **Customer** table but it insert null value to **CustomerInfo** table as well.      
2) I just want to update **Customer** table. But it insert null value to **CustomerInfo** also and update back the `PK` to **Customer**'s `FK`.

Comment: You've posted everything... except your code.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, I have update my post about how I call to create & update. Any clue?

Comment: Well the code inserting a customer ceates a new CustomerInfo, and sets it as the customerInfo of the persisted customer. Why are you surprised the customerInfo is not null in the DB?

Comment: I have change my code to CustomerInfo customerInfo = entity.getCustomerInfo(). Thanks!